# Query MySQL database find missing email addresses

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to extract email addresses from given list, that **not** persists in MySql database. My query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE `user_email` IN ('myemail@email.com', 'my2email@email.com', 'my3email@email.com')
```

First two email addresses are in database, but the last one is not. My target is to print **only** emails that are **NOT** in database. How is that possible?

Comment: The emails list to check for must be a rowset, not literals list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT 'myemail@email.com' user_email
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'my2email@email.com'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'my3email@email.com') emails_to_check_for
LEFT JOIN users USING (user_email)
WHERE users.user_email IS NULL;
```

Comment: What if I had to check thousands of email addresses?

Comment: @IntoTheDeep Save them to temporary table and use instead of the subquery. `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE emails_to_check_for (user_email VARCHAR(255));`

Answer (score 0):

create a temporary table and insert all the email ids that you want to check

```
create table check_emailid(email_id varchar(255))

insert into check_emailid(email_id )
values('myemail@email.com') 
values('my2email@email.com')
values('my3email@email.com')

select * 
from check_emailid 
where email_id not in (SELECT user_email
                       FROM users)
```